# zf2 get filtered values from form

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-filter

I can't figure out how to get filtered values from a form.

For example in controller I'm just creating a form and check if it's valid or not:

```
$editPersonFormObject->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
if ($editPersonFormObject->isValid()) {
    // saving logic
}
```

The form contains "name" element:

```
$nameObject = new Text('name');
$nameObject->setValue($personRowObject->name);
```

and implements the "getInputFilter" method:

```
$this->filter = new InputFilter();

$this->filter->add(
        array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim')
            ),
   ...
return parent::getInputFilter();
```

And it's ok for validating: a validator gets filtered value without spaces, tags and etc, but when I try to save the value in my model:

```
$personRowObject->name = $formObject->get('name')->getValue();
```

I'm getting the unfiltered value with spaces. Even when I'm trying to get the value via FormInput Filter:

```
$formObject->getInputFilter()->getValues();
```

I get an array of empty values:

```
array(1) {
    ["name"] => string(0) ""
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to retrieve data from a form is by using `$form->getData()`

That will either be an array of values or an object, depending on how your form is set up. The function `getData()` furthermore can only be called, **after** a form has been validated using `$form->isValid()`. The values you return will be filtered, too. As **filtering** happens **before validation**.

Comment: It's ok, I understand, but I get an array of empty strings calling $formObject->getValues() just like array(1) {["name"] => string(0) ""}

Comment: `getData()` not `getValues()` - if the field `name` does not validate properly, the content will be empty `string(0)`. Check `$form->getMessages()`

Answer (score 0):

You could have the object bound with the form:

```
$form->bind($personRowObject);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // this returns an object already populated with the form values, filtered
    $person = $form->getData();
}
```

Your person object needs to have a method `exchangeArray($data)` where you set the desired object properties from the form data.